# Ошибка access violation в задаче с Тимуса

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать задачу с Тимуса:https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1005
Однако там выдает Runtime error (access violation) .
Почему так может быть?В компиляторе нормально все работает

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
long int n,sum1,sum2;
long int *mas = new long int[n];
int func(long int sum1,long int sum2,long int count)
{
if(count<n)
    return min(func(sum1+mas[count],sum2,count+1),func(sum1,sum2+mas[count],count+1));
else return abs(sum1-sum2);
}
 int main ()
{
cin >> n ;
sum1=0;
sum2=0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin>>mas[i];

  cout << func(sum1,sum2,0) << endl;
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: А что такое `new int[n]` ?

Comment: Извините,поправил.Имел ввиду new long int[n];Объявление массива.Был не уверен можно ли так,но в онлайн компиляторе все работает

Comment: Да без разницы. У вас n чему равен в этот момент?

Comment: Хм,да...значение не устанавливал...Возможно это и есть ошибка.Но почему тогда в  онлайн компиляторе работает,а в тимусе может не работать?

Comment: @user376237 Потому что выход за границы массива вызывает неопределенное поведение. Может возникнуть ошибка, а может "просто работать".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этот момент

```
long int n,sum1,sum2;
long int *mas = new long int[n];
```

n как глобальная переменная равен 0. Память не выделена.

Перенесите сюда:

```
int main ()
{
    cin >> n ;
    mas = new long int[n];
```